# Sentry ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, ssl, sentry

I've set up Sentry last night from my home network to log exceptions and it worked flawlessly. When I came to work and tried to run the exact same code through the work network I get the following exception:

```
2019-05-08 10:56:02.725  WARN 10204 --- [pool-1-thread-1] 

i.s.c.AbstractConnection.lockdown        : Initiated a temporary lockdown because of exception: An exception occurred while submitting the event to the Sentry server.
2019-05-08 10:56:02.727 ERROR 10204 --- [pool-1-thread-1] io.sentry.connection.AsyncConnection     : An exception occurred while sending the event to Sentry.

io.sentry.connection.ConnectionException: An exception occurred while submitting the event to the Sentry server.
    at io.sentry.connection.HttpConnection.doSend(HttpConnection.java:216) ~[sentry-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at io.sentry.connection.AbstractConnection.send(AbstractConnection.java:76) ~[sentry-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at io.sentry.connection.AsyncConnection$EventSubmitter.run(AsyncConnection.java:185) ~[sentry-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at io.sentry.connection.HttpConnection.doSend(HttpConnection.java:168) ~[sentry-1.7.5.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I've added [this .pem file](https://sentry.io/_static/getsentry/ssl/getsentry.pem) to my cacert and explicitly pointed to it in the VM options via:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\ocuinr\cacerts 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

But this doesn't help.

The [SSL docs](https://docs.sentry.io/ssl/) mention:

> Certain versions of the JRE already include the DigiCert certificates

... which leads me to believe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Do I need to get an exception added to the work firewall, or can I disable SSL verification like suggested in the [Python docs](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/transports/)?

Comment: any luck on this @Nanor? I encountered the same issue in different networks.

Comment: @Bere Unfortunately I can't remember if it was resolved or I just gave up, apologies